# Data passed via Segment API does not show up on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Segment.com .NET APIs to pass data to Google Analytics. But even after 3 to 4 days The data has not appeared on Google.  Nor I can see data in the Debugger section of Segment's Account Dashboard.

I wonder what is happening?  Is there any special configuration to be done at Google side for the data to appear ?    or is there anything else I am missing.

---

Following is the code used.

```
Analytics.Initialize("pOAM4 Some-KEY PrAC",new Config().SetAsync(false));
Analytics.Client.Identify("BillGates", new Segment.Model.Traits() {
                                      { "name", uname  },
                                      { "email", uemail },
                                      { "friends", counter }
                                                               });
Analytics.Client.Track("BillGates", "Purchased Item", new Segment.Model.Properties() {
       { "Item", itemcounter},
        { "revenue", 39.95 },
        { "shipping", "2-day" }
    });
Analytics.Client.Track("BillGates", "Logged Out", new Segment.Model.Properties()   {}  );
```

I am executing them several times.... and I expect something to appear on Google Analytics Dashboard, but its bank.

Any help from anyone who have used Segment.com APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't getting to the Segment debugger, that means that something is probably wrong in your implementation, either API keys or improperly formatted code and I'd recommend using the logging that's built into this lib, you can use it like so.

```
using Segment;

Segment.Logger.Handlers += Logging_Handler;

void Logging_Handler(Level level, string message, Dict args) 
{
if (args != null)
{
    foreach (string key in args.Keys) {
        message += String.Format(" {0}: {1},", "" + key, "" + args[key]);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[Analytics] [{0}] {1}", level, message));
}
```

The one thing that jumps out to me is that you're calling `new Segment.Model.Properties()` in your `.Track()` and `new Segment.Model.Traits()` in your `.Identify()`.

I've always used `new Properties()` in `.Track()` and `new Traits()` in `.Identify()` like so

```
Analytics.Client.Identify("<<userId>>", new Traits() {
{ "name", "#{ user.name }" },
{ "email", "#{ user.email }" },
{ "friends", 29 }
});

Analytics.Client.Track("<<userId>>", "Purchased Item", new Properties() {
{ "revenue", 39.95 },
{ "shipping", "2-day" }
});
```

The code for this lib is all open-source and available on github [here](https://segment.com/docs/libraries/net/#troubleshooting) and the [Segment docs are pretty thorough as well](https://segment.com/docs/libraries/net).

Good luck!